# What are the restrictions on infinite sums of measures?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Select a positive natural number at random. For all n, the probability of selecting that number n is zero. Yet the sum for all n of (probability of selecting number n) is 1. So there is some restriction in measure theory (maybe it's obvious and I've just forgotten it) which prevents us from constructing that sum from 1 to infinity of (probability of selecting number n) in the usual way. What?

Comment: "Select a positive natural number at random". What do you mean by random? You need to specify some kind of distribution with which you draw.

Answer (score 0):

In probability you are allowed to have distinct members of countable sets have a positive probability but it becomes a little more tricky for uncountable sets such as defining a probability measure on a (0,1) interval. As you may know, mathematics takes the perspective of thinking of these probability of set happening as volume or density of the set. So they way I like to think of why a probability for $P(X=a)=0$ for $a\in(0,1)$ if $(0,1)$ is support of X is that if look at area of square on a 2D plane each point doesn't have a volume but regions do.

Also you can define a probability measure on all the natural where each number has a positive probability the poisson distribution is an example.

I don't know if this exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry. I thought about it a bit more after posting, and realised that the problem is not summing as such, but the unbounded sets involved. Thus, for example, you just can't define a probability measure on Z+ with each number having the same probability. Sorry again. 45 years since I last studied measure theory, and it takes a while for the thoughts to resurface...